# Method 'Worksheets' of object'_Global' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched through quite a few topics looking for a solution and most responses just fix the problem without explaining why.

For some odd reason 2 people who use a worksheet I created are getting a Run-time error '1004' after enabling content. Even though another guy and myself have no issues. The error points to the Value1 line. **"sortlist for Vlookup"** is a **hidden** sheet.

> Method 'Worksheets' of object'_Global' failed

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Dim Value1 As String
Dim Value2 As String
Dim Value3 As String

Value1 = Worksheets("sortlist for Vlookup").Range("B30") '<-- Where the error points
Value2 = Worksheets("sortlist for Vlookup").Range("A31")
Value3 = Worksheets("sortlist for Vlookup").Range("B2")

With Worksheets("input")
    If Range("B14").Value = Value1 Then
    Range("B15").Value = "0"
    End If
    If Range("B13").Value = Value2 Then
    Range("B20").Value = "0"
    End If
    If Range("B11").Value = Value3 Then
    Range("B25").Value = Value3
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Even it's hidden, you still can refer to its cells. Check spelling...

Comment: Spelling seems to be fine. It works for me, just not others

Comment: Try to use programmatic name (you can see it in VBE - it's the one which is *not* in parenthesis).

Comment: I am not sure what is meant by this. You are hinting that the problem doesn't lie within the tab name but part of the "Worksheets"?

Comment: Oh, do I need to use "SET"?

Comment: In VB Editor's Project Explorer you see your sheets. There are two names: one in parenthesis and one - is not. For instance, `Sheet1 (sortlist for Vlookup)`. So, `Sheet1` is programmatic name. Use this name instead of `Worksheets("sortlist for Vlookup")`.

Comment: Interesting, I suppose that is a much better habit to get into so sheet names can be dynamic. Your solution worked. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! :)